# Can't figure out the proper class relationships

Tags: c#, oop, uml, relationship, class-diagram

I am not experienced in making class diagrams so I decided to post here to get some help.

Problems with the following diagram:

1. Can't figure out the relationship I need in order to have a
   HumanManager only exist if its assigned a User.
2. Don't know if the relationship I have created between the
   TeamStats class and the Teams and Leagues is the best one

Football Manager Class Diagram:

[image]

Can someone help me out with understanding what I need to do and clarify what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Is a `RobotManager` a robot that has the role of manager, or a person managing robots? In the first case you might want to revisit the generalization from `Manager` to `Person` as a robot is not a person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I would suggest you use something like a coupling/registration table to assign the HumanManager to the user, since the humanmanager can be assigned to more users and perhaps there can be more managers assigned to the same user. So this way you are on the safe side. This way you can possibly make a field 'managertype' and remove the robotmanager table.

[image]

2. This will work. Only watch the Fixture, because one fixture may apply to more then one team.  So make this a many to many relationship.I would end up with something like this: But you can iterate on this, and dont forget about the PK FK relations.
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. Existence depending on an assignment

> have a HumanManager only exist if it's assigned a User

This requirement just needs an additional association between `HumanManager` and `User` with a multiplicity of 1 on the side of `User`.

The multiplicities on this associaition would need further analysis: 1 means 1..1 (i.e. at minimum one and at maximum 1).  But you could also have 1..*  if more than one `User` could be assigned to the same `HumanManager`.  Conversely,  on the side of `HumanManager` you could have 1 if the `User` is in reality supposed to be the `HumanManager` (one-to-one association), or * if a user could be assigned to several human managers.

*Note: it could be tempting to associate a HumanManager to a Person instead of a User. But this changes the semantics:  user are a subset of persons, and you could associate a human manager to a person which is not a user.  I leave it up to you to see if this could be or not a problem depending on the context and the requirements*

#### Relation between stats and classes on which the stats are performed

Classes for stats is always a difficult topic,  since we use to make stats on instances of with criteria and aggregation that might change dynamically.  In your case, it seems that TeamStat has as properties that are basic stats that belong to a single Team for a single season of a given league.  This makes it a valid construct, provided that we keep in mind that its Basic/Elementary stats, and not all the statistics we could derive from these numbers.

I'd recommend to remove the  shared aggregation (white diamond) as it does not add any value.  But I would recommend to show the `1` (Team) - `*` (TeamStats) multiplicities.

`League` and the `TeamStats` both have a `season`.  I therefore understand that the basic `TeamStats` make only sense for a given `League` and the `League` already implies a season.  Therefore, remove the season  from the `TeamStats`, since it is provided by the `League`.  As an alternative, you could consider making the `Season` a separate class. I think this could make the diagram more precise (e.g. allow also to consider stats aggregated by league over multiple seasons), although it would increase slightly its complexity.

Last but not least, you may remove the composition (black diamond) between League and TeamStats: a simple association with mandatory multiplicity (`1` or `1..*`) better reflects the semantic relation between the league and the stats than a composition. But this could be debated depending on the context.